# Parameters hide instance variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, hidden-variables

Is there a way to give a parameter to a method the same name as an instance variable in Objective-C without hiding that variable?

For instance,

```
- (void)doSomething:(id)object
{
    self.object = object;
}
```

The code above gives the warning "local declaration of 'object' hides instance variable."

The obvious solution is to name the parameter arguments differently, but I find it annoying having to choose a name like "anObject" instead of "object".

Comment: When you say "local variable", I think you mean "instance variable". Parameters are one kind of local variable.

Comment: Thanks outis.  I corrected the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use dot notation to access properties (as you do in the example), but instance variables have only one access path, so the only solution if you want to access both an instance variable and a local variable is to give them different names.

Formally speaking, this is related to the restrictions on [alpha conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B1-conversion) in lambda calculus, specifically that a bound variable should remain bound and a free variable remain free.

If you don't like the "an" prefix for locals, you can use the "_" prefix convention for instance variables, as they're also effectively protected variables.

```
@interface AClass {
    id _object;
}
@property (retain) id object;
@end

@implementation AClass
@synthesize object = _object;

- (void)doSomething:(id)object
{
    [_object befriend:object];
}
...
```

Of course, "_" reads as "my", so it may be just as distasteful as "a"/"an" before parameters. Renaming is the best solution as instance and local variables have different roles, and their names should reflect this.

Comment: Actually, you can access ivars with self->object.  Also, Apple "reserves" the underscore prefix for its own use, although no one seems to pay any attention to that.  Personally, I use i_ as the prefix for my ivars, which also helps distinguish them from properties.

Comment: Adding the underscores also let you differentiate between `_object = something` and `self.object = something` which are two completely different bits of code.

Comment: What if the method in question is actually the setter for the instance variable? Anything different?

Comment: @Tony: think about that for a bit. What would happen? Once you've thought about it, try it in a debugger.

Comment: @Peter: actually, the "underscore reserved by Apple" refers only to Apple's internal code libraries. For your own code you are free to use underscore-prefixed variable names, and Apple actually mentions that underscore prefixes can be used to signal the difference between the instance _variable and its accessor method self.variable. (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE) Personally I would not prefix instance vars at all but rather change the names of method params.

Comment: I believe Apple only reserves the underscore prefix for method names, not ivars.  Xcode autocompletes ivars starting with an underscore (i.e., @synthesize "myVar = _" will autocomplete to _myVar.

Answer (score 13):

You might be able to do something like `self->object = object`, but the Objective-C convention (derived from Smalltalk) is to prefix parameters with "a" or "an" if the parameter has the same name as an instance variable.

Comment: +1 for this answer. The public Cocoa APIs use parameter names like "anObject" and "aDictionary" to differentiate from instance variables. In addition to following convention, this makes it less likely to refer to the wrong variable by accident, and somewhat easier to refactor.

Comment: This is the Apple-recommended solution, plus it's a nice convention, IMO. "- (void)doSomething:(id)anObject".